# jquery flexbox works at localhost(when debugged), but not after publish

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

The jquery plugin named ["flexbox"](http://flexbox.codeplex.com/) works fine in localhost, but doesn't work at server.

**In localhost debug(working version):**

[image: working at localhost(when debugged)]

**After publish to server(not working):**

[image: not working after publish]

Response of the not-working version(after publish to server) returns as response => `"results": []` as seen in firebug. I use this component in a asp .net mvc project. The problem exists for browsers I tested in(chrome, firefox, explorer). What could reason be ?

Comment: if server returns "results":[] then it's most likely problem at server than jquery.

Comment: I agree with @SachinG if "results":[] is returned it means that you are not getting any response back. Are you sure you have changed the code that gets the data, so that it fits the server instead of localhost?

Comment: The application except flexbox  works  after publish. Code is the same as in localhost debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some search and trial, I solved it accidentally. The problem is not about flexbox. It is about query.

the query was :

```
query = @"SELECT L.KURUM_NO, L.AD  KURUMADI                               
          FROM LABARATUVAR L WHERE L.AD LIKE '%" + q + "%'";
```

and  now:

```
query = @"SELECT L.KURUM_NO, L.AD  KURUMADI                               
          FROM LABARATUVAR L WHERE L.AD LIKE '%'||:q||'%'";
```

I only parametrized the query in C#. I couldn't understand the reason, but now it works at localhost and server.